# Ternary operator on javascript and PHP, different output

Tags: php, javascript, ternary-operator, unary-operator

I wanted to do [Fizzbuzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bizz_buzz) in php by using unary if, but the output is not what I expect, and I didn't understood why, so I have copy-paste the code to javascript, and now the result is as expected. Why?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
papa ='Javascript Output: ';
for($i=1;$i <= 10; $i++){
papa += ($i %5 === 0 && $i %3 === 0) ? 'FizzBuzz' : ($i % 3 === 0) ? 'Fizz' : ($i % 5 === 0) ? 'Buzz' : $i;
$('#result').text(papa);
}
})
</script>
<?php
echo 'PHP Output: ';
for($i=1;$i <= 10; $i++){
$papa ($i %5 === 0 && $i %3 === 0) ? 'FizzBuzz' : ($i % 3 === 0) ? 'Fizz' : ($i % 5 === 0) ? 'Buzz' : $i;
echo $papa;
}
?>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Output

```
PHP Output: 12Buzz4BuzzBuzz78BuzzBuzz
Javascript Output: 12Fizz4BuzzFizz78FizzBuzz
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ternary operator (which you called "unary if") in javascript uses right associativity and the same operator in php uses left associativity.

- [javascript operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)
- [php operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Yes, this could be fixed with more parenthesis (as well as any problem relating operator precedence).

Comment: also note the super cool 2 versions of logical "and" and "or" and their difference in precedence! (in PHP)

Answer (score 2):

```
in PHP, change 
    ($i %5 === 0 && $i %3 === 0) ? 'FizzBuzz' : ($i % 3 === 0) ? 'Fizz' : ($i % 5 === 0) ? 'Buzz' : $i;
    to:
    ($i %5 === 0 && $i %3 === 0) ? 'FizzBuzz' : ($i % 3 === 0) ? 'Fizz' : (($i % 5 === 0) ? 'Buzz' : $i);
```